# compile time error - stackOverflow, while creating new class instance

Tags: java

below is very simple program which is giving stackOverFlow error. Here is confuse with flow. can someone tell me the exact flow of this program and give me the reason for the corresponding error.

```
package test;

   class Test{

   Test tt = new Test();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test();
   }

}
```

OUTPUT -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:4)
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:4)
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:4)
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:4)
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:4)
    at test.Test.<init>(Test.java:4)
```

Comment: Are you asking what a stack overflow is?

Comment: i know stack over flow error but in this program why i am getting when there is no any recursive call

Comment: @RishiKantMalviya creating an instance of Test creates an instance of Test, which creates an instance of Test, which creates an instance of Test....

Comment: @RishiKantMalviya we can't run your code, it won't compile. You forgot the } to close your constructor. that being said, each new instance of Test creates a new instance of Test, which creates a new instance of Test, ... well, you get the point

Answer (score 2):

When you do `new Test()`, the instance fields of `Test` will be initialised. In this case, `tt` will be initialised.

Well, how do you initialise `tt`? You call its constructor. When you do so, `tt.tt` will need to be initialised. This will call the constructor again, which tries to initialise `tt.tt.tt`. And it goes on and on like this.

So the `Test` constructor is calling the same `Test` constructor, causing a stack overflow. The situation is kind of like this:

```
Test tt;

public Test() {
    tt = new Test();
}
```

Comment: "kind of like" It's *exactly* like that. Instance initializers get inserted into all constructors that don't invoke `this(...)`, after the `super(...)` call and before the rest of the ctor body.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when the program starts it creates an instance because it is declare outside a method so basically you create and create and create another instance under the main instance.

```
Test tt = new Test();
```

This code create a recursive call. So the result is a StackOverflow. And there you have it.